# Handle JPopupMenu closed

Tags: java, swing, jpopupmenu, jmenuitem, jpopup

I want to highlight some elements on screen, when one JMenuItem in PopupMenu ist selected(mouse over). So i use MouseListener on my JMenuItem with

```
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            highlightOn();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            highlightOff();
        }
```

It works fine, but if i press Esc the popup menu will be closed, without clean the highligt. How can i intercept the closing of JPopupMenu to handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you look at

1. `PopupMenuListener`

better could be

1. `JMenuItem`(s) can returns `ButtonModel`,
2. `ButtonModel` returns `isRollover()`, `isArmend()`, `isPressed()` e.i.
3. each of `JButtons JComponents` (JButton, JCheckBox, JRadioButton and JMenuXxx) implemented diferrent methods from `ButtonModel`

Answer (score 7):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
myPopupMenu.addPopupMenuListener(new PopupMenuListener() {

     @Override
     public void popupMenuCanceled(final PopupMenuEvent e) {
         highlightOff();
     }

     @Override
     public void popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(final PopupMenuEvent e) {
         highlightOff();
     }

     @Override
     public void popupMenuWillBecomeVisible(final PopupMenuEvent e) { }
}
```

Just remember to add the listener before you make it visible, or inside its constructor.

Comment: +1 for PopupMenuListener, btw JMenuXxx have got own another Listeners, PopupMenuListener this doesn't works for particular JMenuItem is highlighted.... or deselected